# List of Android Gradle Plugin functions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

There are a lot of functions available for a `build.gradle` file in Android Studio. Is there any documentation for those functions? I have copied great part of my build file from here, but i get some errors recently and want to look up which functions are valid and which are not.
Im using the canary version of AS, i don't expect much help on the internet. So i'd like to have a look at any documentation.